# How do I add a compiler directive for TMS Web Core websites?

Tags: delphi, compiler-directives, tms-web-core

I can use the following compiler directive code to specify Platform specific code:

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  // This code is for Windows
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF IOS}
  // This code is for iOS
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  // This code is for MacOS
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF LINUX}
  // This code is for Linux
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  // This code is for Android
{$ENDIF}
```

That works for Windows, iOS, MacOS, Linux and Android.

I need to write TMS Web Core specific code now, but what is the compiler directive for TMS Web Core? Is there even one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler directive name for TMS Web Core is `WEBLIB`.

So if you want to have code specifically for TMS Web Core, then you can write:

```
{$IFDEF WEBLIB}
  // Code in here is for TMS Web Core
{$ENDIF}
```

Source: https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/project-compiler-directives-not-working/19858

Comment: It would help if you explained where you found this information.

Comment: @KenWhite Sure. I found it here in this forum post: https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/project-compiler-directives-not-working/19858

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you cited it as your source in your question, so that proper attribution is given? I believe that is a requirement of the site guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite Source added 